# My margin left is not working, why

Tags: html, css

Why my margin-left property don't work? I want use class to work with margins, not css inside html.
Here is https://jsfiddle.net/mhzhvfo2/

```
<div class="col span_1_of_12 margin_5_of_12">
 1 of 12
  </div>
```

Comment: `.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }` is overriding it. Check developer tools in your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two are overriding your margin.

```
.col:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0% 0 0% 0%;
}
```

You could remove the class `col` to resolve this.

```
<div class="span_1_of_12 margin_5_of_12">
 1 of 12
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove `col` if you want.

But instead, you could also add `!important` in the `.margin_5_of_12` class so that it will ignore previous rules applied and apply the rules of this class.

```
.margin_5_of_12 {
margin-left: 41.66% !important;
}
```